# Oracle Linux 7 bash script, get environment value from other user

Tags: bash

I am working with Oracle E-Business Suite R12 on Oracle Linux 7 environment. For a bash script, I need to read one of the environment variables from the user applmgr as user root.

```
su applmgr -c 'source /u02/oracle/apps/EBSapps.env run;echo $RUN_BASE;'
```

The above does echo the RUN_BASE variable. My requirement is to assign environment variable value to a local variable within the script. I tried to the following

```
BASE_PATH="$(su applmgr -c 'source /u02/oracle/apps/EBSapps.env run;echo $RUN_BASE;)"
```

That was adding up the .env file printf outputs also. How do I isolate only $RUN_BASE value?

Comment: `BASE_PATH="$(su applmgr -c 'source /u02/oracle/apps/EBSapps.env run >/dev/null 2>&1;echo $RUN_BASE;)"` may work. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To exclude all output from the `source ...` command before the `echo` command in the subshell, redirect its stdout and stderr to `/dev/null`:

`BASE_PATH=$(su applmgr -c 'source /u02/oracle/apps/EBSapps.env run >/dev/null 2>&1; echo "$RUN_BASE"')`

(Side note: the example command in your post had an unclosed single quote, I fixed that too.)

Comment: Actually I edited the existing code with /dev/null and didn't notice the original answer missing the closing single quote. Anyway, not only it did solve my problem, gave me better ideas to better the bash script as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
su - applmgr -c "[you command ...]"
```